# C++ Custom compare function for list::sort

Tags: c++, list, function-pointers

Hi I'm having trouble compiling a simple piece of code. I am creating a class which implements a Deck of cards, and I want to create a shuffle method using the list::short method.

Relevant code:

**deck.h**

```
#ifndef _DECK_H
#define _DECK_H

#include <list>
#include <ostream>

#include "Card.h"
#include "RandomGenerator.h"

using namespace std;

class Deck {
private:
    static const int CARD_NUMBER = Card::CARDS_PER_SUIT*Card::SUIT_NUMBER;
    list<Card *> *cards;
    RandomGenerator rg;

public:
    Deck();
    ~Deck();
    void shuffle();
private:
    bool const compareRandom(const Card *a, const Card *b);

};

#endif  /* _DECK_H */
```

deck.cc:

```
#include "Deck.h"

/**
 * Fills the deck with a set of 52 cards
 */
Deck::Deck() {
    cards = new list<Card *>();
    for(int i = 0; i < CARD_NUMBER; i++)
        cards->push_back(
                new Card(
                    Card::Suit(int(i/Card::CARDS_PER_SUIT)),
                    i%Card::CARDS_PER_SUIT)
        );
}

Deck::~Deck() {
    gather();
    for(list<Card *>::iterator c = cards->begin(); c != cards->end(); c++)
        delete *c;
    delete cards;
}

bool const Deck::compareRandom(const Card *a, const Card *b) {
    return rg.randomBool();
}

void Deck::shuffle() {
    cards->sort(compareRandom);
}
```

The compiler shows the next message (ignore line numbers):

```
Deck.cc: In member function ‘void Deck::shuffle()’:
Deck.cc:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::list<Card*, std::allocator<Card*> >::sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/list.tcc:303: note: candidates are: void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::sort() [with _Tp = Card*, _Alloc = std::allocator<Card*>]
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/list.tcc:380: note:                 void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::sort(_StrictWeakOrdering) [with _StrictWeakOrdering = const bool (Deck::*)(const Card*, const Card*), _Tp = Card*, _Alloc = std::allocator<Card*>]
```

The problem has to be on the compareRandom reference that I'm not using correctly, I cant find googling the answer to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a side note, your code would be much simpler if you didn't store pointers to `Card`'s, but just had `std::list<Card>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can I say something :)

First, don't store a pointer to `Card`, just store the cards directly in the container. If you insist on storing pointers to them for any reason, use `shared_ptr<Card>` from `Boost`. Second, you can use `std::random_shuffle` and pass your `random-number-generator` to it instead of implementing your your shuffle function.

---

May I say something again :)

This is what I have in mind, unless you have to use `list` for whatever reason, although I don't `see` that reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

class Card
{
// ...
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<Card> Deck;
    Deck deck;

    // ... fill deck with cards.

    // There is an optional third parameter,
    // if you need to pass YOUR random-number-generator!
    // If you do, I recommend Boost implementation.
    std::random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
}
```

I like to deal with containers directly in `C++`, though you may not like it. Also, if you see that `std::vector` has performance issues in your case, you could just replace the typedef with `std::deque`:

```
typedef std::deque<Card> Deck;
```

Comment: In which case you can't use `sort`... (it's not a strict weak ordering)

Comment: Thanks didn't know there was a stl shuffle algorythm.

Comment: cant use:
random_shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end());
with a list :(

Comment: "cant use: random_shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end()); with a list :(" - Consider switching to std::vector then. Use a container that suits your needs. :)

Comment: @eliocs I am not sure why you have to use a list? I'll post a piece of code as an example of what I have in my mind :)

Answer (score 7):

compareRandom is a member function, it has type `bool (Deck::*)(const Card*, const Card*)` which means you can't call it like `f(a,b)`, which is how sort will be calling it. You can make compareRandom a static or standalone function, or use a functor to adapt it to a specific instance of Deck.

Comment: Neat.  Now I can delete my answer :)

Answer (score 6):

BTW - You cannot shuffle using sort :) Sort makes some assumptions on compare function.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from what others said: you can use <strike>`std::shuffle`</strike> `std::random_shuffle` (something I learned today, hurray!), I might add you *cannot* use a random function as a sort criterion.

`sort` takes a strict weak ordering as comparator, meaning that if `a < b` (or `compareRandom(a,b)` returns false, then `b < a` (`compareRandom(b,a)` returns true) and `b == a` should return false, which you can never guarantee with a random function.  The behaviour of `sort` is undefined in this case.  I don't know if it even ends...

Comment: There is no `std::shuffle`, only `std::random_shuffle`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the error in [Logan Capaldo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415608/c-custom-compare-function-for-listsort/1415628#1415628). Now you could replace `compareRandom` with functor in the following way:

```
...
private:
struct compareRandom {
  // it shouldn't give a random compare result. 
  // sort will not work (in Visual C++ 2008 it gives runtime assert)
  bool operator()(const Card *a, const Card *b) { return rg.randomBool(); }
};
...
```

Then use it

```
void Deck::shuffle() {
    cards->sort( compareRandom() );
}
```

Comment: Except that this won't really "shuffle" things correctly. Without a pure predicate, sort will not behave predictably, but that doesn't mean that you're getting any sort of halfway decent random distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to use `std::random_shuffle` instead. It won't work on a `list` but it will work on a `deque` or `vector`, so unless you need list properties, I suggest you use another container. If you must use a list, try this:

```
void Deck::shuffle()
{
    vector<Card*> temp(cards->begin(), cards->end());
    random_shuffle(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    cards->assign(temp.begin(), temp.end());
}
```